# jQuery works only localhost

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have js game that works well on localhost (apache2), but on my server (and on github pages - where the source is from) the game doesn't work. **jQuery is loaded and in chrome console works fine.** It seems that `$(document).ready` doesn't work. The code for main.js is here and this is the [github repository link](http://github.com/dracconi/reflex-io). words.json is a 1mb words dictonary. The game on github worked before. Any ideas?

```
$.getScript("js/timer.js");
$.getScript("js/functions.js");
$.getJSON( "js/words.json").then(start);

var typos = 0;
var item;
var typedwords = [];
var correct;
var words;
var words_obj;

function start(response) {
  words = response["words"];
  $("#times").html("");
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  if (getParameterByName("seed") == undefined) {
    window.location.replace(window.location.href + "?seed=" + makeid());
  };

  Math.seed = getParameterByName("seed");

  $("#start").click(function() {
    $(".header").slideUp();
    regenerate();
  });

  $("body").keyup(function(e) {
    if (String.fromCharCode(e.which).toLowerCase() == item.charAt(correct).toLowerCase()) {
      $("#"+correct).addClass("active");
      correct ++;
      if (correct == item.length) {
        typedwords.push(item);
        $("#times").append(time.toFixed(2)+" ("+item+")<br>")
        regenerate();
      };
    }
    else {
      time += 1;
      typos++;
    };
  });
});

function regenerate() {
  stopTimer();
  saveLastTime();
  resetTimer();
  startTimer();

  correct = 0;
  item = words[Math.floor(Math.seededRandom(words.length,0))];
  text = "";

  for (i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
    text += "<span id='" + i +"'>"+item.charAt(i)+"</span>";
  };

  $("#text").html("");
  $("#text").html(text);
}
```

Comment: You need to include the jQuery library from somewhere.  CDNs are a good place to start.  Chrome console has some basic selector features already in place.

Comment: [github.io link](https://dracconi.github.io/reflex-io/)

Comment: @Sid I said **jQuery is loaded**. I'm using jQuery 3.0 from JQ CDN.

Comment: Why can't you just read your console errors? `getParameterByName is not defined` You must wait all your `$.getScript` before start.

Comment: @vp_arth Umm that is error in jQuery. So how to fix this?

Comment: There is not any global `getParameterByName` symbol in `jQuery`. It's your own symbol. Just wait while it finishes loading

Comment: @vp_arth is something like this
`$.getScript("js/timer.js").then(function(){
$.getScript("js/functions.js").then(function(){
$.getJSON( "js/words.json").then(start)})` fix this?

Comment: yes, like this. And move your `$(document).ready` code to `start`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using `$.getScript` to include JS code in your page. That's not the correct way as `$.getScript` is asynchronous and is not guaranteed to complete before the DOM is considered loaded and all the `$(document).ready(...)` callbacks are called and you're accessing a variable defined in those files from one such callback.

You should include the two scripts using `<script src=...></script>` in your HTML:

```
<script src="js/timer.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="js/functions.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: so the easiest approach is the anwser

Comment: Yup @qcperek you should add it

Answer (score -1):

Another way to approach this is do in your HTML

```
<script>
  if (window.jQuery) {
    document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="js/timer.js"><\/script>')
    document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="js/functions.js"><\/script>')
  }
</script>
```